# Separate home page per domain in multilingual setup (i18n)

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, domain-access

I have a multisite Drupal with **2 domains**, that should have **separate home pages**, but I can't get it working. I've created a node for each.

Now, I've tried to configure it in the Configuration > Site information > **Default Home Page** panel. There is note on top of the page: "This form is domain-sensitive, be sure you select the proper domain before saving." ; Therefore I guess that "home page" parameter is per domain?

But it doesn't work : each time I change this field (value : node/92), **all domains are affected**.

Is it supposed to work? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is this multisite ?

Comment: Yes, that's what Domain Access is made for, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some search, it is a known conflict between Domain Access and **I18N** : http://drupal.org/node/1650498

As written, the fix is to :

- upgrade i18n to version 1.6 (or latest)
- upgrade Variable to 2.0 (or latest)
- upgrade Domain Access to latest
- **enable and set Domain Variable module.**

Then,

- Go to Domains List > Variables Tab > Site Informations > Check "Default Home Page"
- Go to your domain > You have 2 parameters tabs > Go to the * *2nd* * Parameters Tab > Site informations > set your Default Home Page for this domain.

That should work perfectly !

---

NOTE : There are 2 others ways of setting different frontpages that DOES NOT WORK (at least for me) :

- Configuration > Site information > Default Home Page
- Domain > 1st Parameters Tab > Site Home Page

Don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

I would

1. Setup a "Page manager"-page, and call it "Front".
2. Set the homepage to "/front".
3. Create one variant for every domain in the front-page. Fill with relevant content.
4. Create a ctools "Domain access plugin". That wouldn't be many rows of code, see my brief [tutorial](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37010/separate-frontpage-per-domain/37012#37012)
5. Use the access plugin to setup a selection rule for every variant/domain.